# Use named_struct function in Hive with all the columns of a table

Tags: hadoop, hive

In Hive, you can use a function `named_struct` in order to create a list of key value pairs; the keys are usually the column names and the values are the values in the corresponding column. For example,

```
$hive> select id, named_struct('foo', name, 'address', address) as list from users;
id list
1  {'foo':'Alice', 'address':'Wonderland'}
2  {'foo':'Bob', 'address':'Portland'}
...
```

However, in order to make the list, I needed to explicitly write each column name. Is there any way to avoid doing this with either `named_struct` or some other similar function?

I expect to be able to write something like (assuming `users` has only three columns).

```
$hive> select id, named_struct(*) as list from users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using all columns you don't need a named_struct. Something like `struct("*")` will work.